# Read Multiple json object from a json file in Go

Tags: json, go, go-structtag

I am trying to read the following json objects from the json file. So the number of objects are not predefined, they can be multiple or just one.

So I tried making this struct but I am not able to read it properly. I want to parse the elements inside the json object.

```
type HostList struct {
    HostList {}Host
}

type Host struct {
    IP       string `json: "ip"`
    Netmask  string `json: "netmask"`
    Gateway  string `json: "gateway"`
    Mac      string `json: "mac"`
    Hostname string `json: "hostname"`
    Callback string `json: "callback"`
}
```

And I want to read this Json file:

```
[
    {
        "ip": "4.3.2.10",
        "netmask": "255.255.255.234",
        "gateway": "4.3.2.1",
        "mac": "12:34:af:56:54:jj",
        "hostname": "cds1.yyy.com",
        "callback": ""
    },
    {
        "ip": "4.3.2.11",
        "netmask": "255.255.255.234",
        "gateway": "4.3.2.1",
        "mac": "12:34:af:55:54:jj",
        "hostname": "cds2.yyy.com",
        "callback": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: `    HostList {}Host` is not valid Go. It won't compile. Is that a typo?

Comment: What have you tried? What issue did you run into? Please show your attempt and describe specifically what problems you had. This seems fairly straightforward, aside from the typo where `{}Host` should be `[]Host`.

Comment: You can just create a slice of Hosts, i.e. `hostsSlice := []Host` and then `unmarshal` your json into that hostsSlice variable for easy management. Sample playground code [here](https://goplay.space/#-dSZbkFmzdc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below

```
type HostList []struct {
  IP       string `json:"ip"`
  Netmask  string `json:"netmask"`
  Gateway  string `json:"gateway"`
  Mac      string `json:"mac"`
  Hostname string `json:"hostname"`
  Callback string `json:"callback"`
}
```

You can use this site https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ for generating Go struct from JSON.